# String compare isn't working correctly in C

Tags: c, string, scanf, strcmp

I can't figure out why my string compare isn't comparing correctly. This is for C.

It's reading from a file that is set up like this:

```
1 - ls              
2 - cd                   
3 - history
```

If I type !c it's suppose to grab the last used string that started with 'c' and run the command. Yet it never goes into the if(strcmp(())=0) line.

Part of my code is here:

```
  char currLine[MAXINPUTLINE];

    else if (isalpha(input[1])){
        int count = 1;
        fileRead = fopen(".simpleshell_history", "r");
        while(fscanf(fileRead, "%s\n", currLine) != EOF){
            printf(input+1);
            printf(currLine);
            if(strcmp((input+1), currLine) == 0){
                printf("%s\n", currLine);
                parse(currLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what the printf in the while loop prints, I can't figure out how to fix this and I've been stuck on it for a while. This is when I enter '!c'

```
 c
 1c
 -c
 lsc
 2c
 -c
 cdc
 3c
 -c
 historyc
 4c
 -c
 !c!c
```

Comment: What do you have at the output?

Comment: What do you mean? Right now it's suppose to go into the if statement and output the currLine but it's only looping through the while loop and not going into the if statement.

Comment: you have printf-s there. What do they print?

Comment: Do you check that your input[...] has appropriate lenghth? (at least 2).

Comment: Do you really need to check input[1]? may be you meant input[0]?

Comment: I just updated my OP with what printf prints out. I need input[1] because it checks the second char after '!' to see if it's a alphabet, if I put input[0] it'll always compare with the first char which is '!'

Comment: Your problem is with the manner in which you get `input`.  It likely has a trailing `\n`.  Show how you get `input`.

Comment: I am having trouble deciphering the output.  The first output line is 'c' which is (input + 1).  The second line is "1c" which is currLine.  So your history file is numbered?  What's the rest?

Comment: It's reading from a file which I have an example of up there.. it's listed as "# - string" I'm not sure how I'll be able to skip the numbering and '-' and just read from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `input` is the string `!c` and you are looking to match that against the line `2 - cd`, you will have to be careful. `strcmp` will definitely not work, as it will only return success if the two strings it is comparing are exact matches.

In order to test whether one string (`cd`) starts with another string (`c`), you want to use `strncmp()`, which will take a limit on the number of characters to compare.

Also: you will need to be careful to start comparing from the second character of `input` (skipping the `!`) and from the fifth character of `currLine` (skipping the `2 -` characters).

This should get you there:

```
    while (fgets(currLine, sizeof currLine, fileRead) != NULL) {
        printf(input+1);
        printf(currLine);
        if (strncmp(input + 1, currLine + 4, strlen(input)-1) == 0) {
            printf("%s\n", currLine);
            parse(currLine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried your solution, however it still isn't going into the if statement. I showed the output of the while loop down below in my answers.

Comment: Does `input` have a trailing newline character, as suggested elsewhere? If so, try `strlen(input)-2` instead to prevent it from trying to compare the newline from `input` with the `d` in `currLine`.

Comment: Yes you're right, now when I printf however it prints the whole line including the number which I don't need it to but I think that's a simple fix. At least I hope so, for example it prints out "3 - history" instead of just "history"

Comment: Yes, I expect that will be a straightforward fix.

Answer (score 2):

This loop:

```
while(fscanf(fileRead, "%s\n", currLine) != EOF) {
```

will read whitespace delimeted tokens into `currLine` rather than lines.  So the first iteration will be `1`, the second `-`, the 3rd `ls`, etc as you are seeing with your printfs.  The name `currLine` suggests you want to read lines rather than tokens.

You then compare the read tokens with the rest of your input line which is apparently `"c\n"`.  Since you never get a token with a newline, it never matches.  Even if you got rid of the newline, it would never match, as your file does not contain the token `c`

**edit**

You say you want to compare the rest of the input line against a prefix of the command on
the line.  To do that you want to first figure out how long the prefix is, then use strncmp.  You also want to parse the line from the file to separate the command from the index.  So you could do something like:

```
else if (isalpha(input[1])){
    int count = 1;
    int pfxlen = 1;
    while (!isspace(input[pfxlen+1])) pfxlen++;
    fileRead = fopen(".simpleshell_history", "r");
    while(fscanf(fileRead, "%d - %[^\n]", &index, currLine) == 2) {
        if(strncmp((input+1), currLine, pfxlen) == 0) {
            printf("%s\n", currLine);
            parse(currLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right it does do that, trying to figure the best way to do this but I'm somewhat clueless.

Comment: What is that you're trying to figure out how to do?  You just say "it isn't working correctly" but don't say what it should do.

Comment: So I'd have to get the "\n" out from the input and also somehow compare only the first char instead of the whole token?

Comment: When I type "!c" into the program it's suppose to pull up the last command used that started with 'c' so if I input "!c" it'll run line #2 which is "cd". If I type "!l" it'll run "ls" which is the first line. It should work if I type "!ls" also but i'll worry about that later. Pretty much it's suppose to function like what's incorporated into C currently with the 'history' and "!string" functions.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that input may contain a trailing newline, while curline definitely will not because of the scanf specification.

Comment: You're right input does have the trailing '\n' at the end of the string but isn't this only comparing the first letter? So that wouldn't matter  would it?

Comment: No, strcmp will compare the entire string.  if you want to compare the first letter then do (input[1] == curline[1])

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work either, will the "1 -" interfere with the string comparison at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the manner in which you get `input`. (notice when you print, it has a line feed).  It has a trailing `\n` and your `currLine` does not.  Hence the compare fails.

Suggest OP uses `fgets()` for both user and file input.

Something like

```
char buf[MAXINPUTLINE];
while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fileRead) != NULL) {
  int LineNo;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d - %s", &LineNo, currLine) != 2) Handle_UnexpectedInput();
  ...
}
```

---

Note: `"%s\n"` does the same as `"%s "` does the same as `"%s\t"`:  `%s` skips optional leading whitespace, then scans non-whitespace.  The whitespace after `s` in `"%s\n"` scans for optional whitespace.

Comment: Maybe I should've included this, I also have a "    while(fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)){" before all of that code. So it does fgets() "input"

Comment: @user2318083  Yes, it gets "!c\n".

Comment: So i just either need to get the '\n' out of the input or add it to the currLine?

Comment: @user2318083 Yes.  I suggest removing the `\n`.  various ways exist.

Comment: Example `size_t len = strlen(input); if (len && input[len-1] == '\n') input[--len] = '\0';`